# Django authentication with custom model

Tags: django, authentication, hash

I have a custom login authentication with mysql table, while logging in how can I compare a hashed password with a plain-password in backends.py (Working fine with plain password)?

```
class MyBackEnd(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        existing_user = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
        if not existing_user:
            # Checking the user Regauth Custom DB.
            user_data = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
            if email == user_data.email:
                user = RegAuth.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return existing_user

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return RegAuth.objects.get(email=email)
        except Exception as e:
            return False
```

Login view

```
    def logauth(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            messages.error(request, 'if part : user is not  None')
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('emp')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'else part : user is None')
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please provide valid credentials')
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/
please check this

Comment: You should never store the user's password in plain text, so you should never compare/retrieve a user's plain password. You should be using Django's built in auth app

Comment: i am not storing plain password , using set_password i convert it to hash and storing them to mysql table..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your authenticate method is trying to accomplish. I would highly recommend you study Django's default authenticate method and get a full understanding of it before diverging into custom overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason to diverge from Django's default authentication backend? I see at least a few issues with your authenticate method;

```
class MyBackEnd(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        # 1. password should not be used to retrieve a user, a pk should suffice
        existing_user = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
        if not existing_user:
            # Checking the user Regauth Custom DB.
            # 2. if the query before didn't yield results, why would it atp?
            user_data = RegAuth.objects.get(email=email,password=password)
            if email == user_data.email:
                # 3. I'm not sure what flow validates this path, could you explain?
                user = RegAuth.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return user
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return existing_user
```

For reference here's Django's default authenticate backend method (notice the use of except/else syntax):

```
 def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

It;

1. Tries to retrieve the user, then;
2. Checks the password, and;
3. Validates the user's state, then;
4. Returns the user object to the caller (successful authentication), or
5. Does NOT return a user to the caller. (failed authentication)

Alternately (no user found), it;

1. Instantiates a user object, and;
2. Sets the password using set_password (which hashes it), then;
3. Does NOT return a user to the caller. (failed authentication)

This alternate flow's usage of `set_password` is meant to mitigate some timing attacks see: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20760

If you want to register new users, reset a user's password, or anything besides *authentication*, the `authenticate` method is ***not*** the right place.

I am aware this is not an answer to your question, but I hope it helps you and possibly others to understand the authentication flow and be critical about diverging from it.